# Configuring Domino Program Document

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I want to define a server task using Domino administrator(8.5.2). So using the menu
Server>>Programs>> and then using "Add Programs" I am trying to define a server task which should run at 12:00 and should repeat after 60 minutes 24 X 7.

But when I try to save the document I get a field validation error in the dialog-box which says:

"You cannot set an interval greater than 0 for single times. The entries you put in the 'Run at times' field includes at least one single time element."

Not sure that I understood the validation error. As per my understanding  I have set 'Run at times' field as 12:00 each day. And the 'Repeat interval of' is 60 minutes. What do these fields mean ?.  For example in my case I want this server task to run after 60 minutes each and 24  X 7.  Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Enter 00:00 - 23:59 as period and 60 minutes as interval. Or enter 12:00; 13:00; 14:00; ... ; 11:00 as times and 0 minutes as interval.

Then you can save the document and it does what you want.

Comment: Yes Thanks. Actually there is no documentation it seems, how to enter a range(and example really) in correct format in this rare free-form entry situation.

Comment: Yes, it appears that you're right about that. The Domino Administrator documentation doesn't describe entering a time range for program documents. It's actually the same, though, as entering a time range for connection documents, which is covered here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_ABOUT_SCHEDULING_TIMES_FOR_REPLICATION.html

Comment: Thanx Richard for clarification. @user1525825: If this answers your question, please accept the answer as solution. Thank you